# Python attribute with simultaneous __get__ and __getitem__ behavior

Tags: python, lazy-loading, python-descriptors

### **EDIT:**

I updated the original title *Python descriptor behavior with _*getitem*_ method* because, as pointed out in the comments, what I am after seems not to be possible using descriptors. But maybe there are other ways to achieve this?

---

I have an object that employs lazy loading of a very large numpy array. It is implemented in such a way that calling `object[idx]` only loads the value corresponding to the index, while `object[:]` produces the full array.

What I would like to do is to use this object as a property-like attribute in another class that omits the need of `[:]` when calling the full array while still maintaining the lazy loading aspect if an index or slice is provided. I can achieve the first when defining a descriptor with an appropriate `__get__` method:

```
class MyDescriptor:
    
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return instance._lazy_array[:]


class Foo:

    lazy_array = MyDescriptor()
    
    def __init__(self, lazy_array_obj):
        self._lazy_array = lazy_array_obj

foo = Foo(lazy_array_obj)
```

Calling `foo.lazy_array` now produces the full array. However, calling `foo.lazy_array[0]` loads the full array and only indexes it afterwards, losing the performance gain from loading only a part of the data.

In theory, what I would need is a `__getitem__` method that supports the descriptor protocol, but that does not seem to exist. Is there any other solution that I am missing here?

**Additional detail:** The lazy array object is a tdms channel produced by the lazy loading of a tdms file using [nptdms](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Descriptors control attribute access, that's it. Once the attribute access is over it's not in the control of the descriptor

Comment: Yes, that's what I found as well. So it would seem that there is no way to achieve what I am after using descriptors? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Yes, I believe there is no way with descriptors, not sure if it is possible ultimately